# Laravel: Casting an array and pushing to it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model where I have added

```
protected $casts = [
    'completed_steps' => 'array'
];
```

My schema is:

```
     Schema::create('runs_accomplished', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('runner_id');
        $table->json('completed_steps')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

So I am doing this in my controller to grab (if one exists already) or create an entry:

```
    $runner = RunsAccomplished::where('runner_id', '=', runner_id())->first();

    if ($runner) {
        $runner->weight = $request->input('weight')
        $runner->save();
    } else {
        $runner = new \App\Models\RunsAccomplished;
        $runner->shop_name = shop_id();
        $runner->weight = $request->input('weight')
        $runner->save();
    }
```

How would I do both: 1) add a value to a new entry and more important, push a value to the existing array without overriding the values inside?

Comment: `RunsAccomplished` doesn't have a `weight`, so `$runner->weight` won't work, right?

Comment: good catch, @Joundill. I just forgot to carry it over in Stackoverflow.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't have weight and shop_name field in your RunsAccomplished migration but you are using it. First, you have to update your migration.

What will be your input for completed_steps? Array or a single element?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add below code into your model like

```
    class RunnerAccomplished extends Model
    {
        protected $casts = [
            'completed_steps' => 'array'
        ];

        public function setCompletedStepsAttribute($value)
        {
            $this->attributes['completed_steps'] = json_encode($value);
        }

        public function getCompletedStepsAttribute($value)
        {
            return json_decode($value);
        }
```

Put below code in your controller

```
$runner = RunsAccomplished::where('runner_id', runner_id())->first();
            $completedSteps = $runner->completed_steps ?? [];

            if (is_array($request->input('completed_steps'))) {
                $completedSteps = array_merge(
                    $completedSteps,
                    $request->input('completed_steps')
                );
            } elseif ($request->input('completed_steps')) {
                array_push($completedSteps, $request->input('completed_steps'));
            }

            if ($runner) {
                $runner->completed_steps = $completedSteps;
                $runner->save();
            } else {
                $runner = new RunnerAccomplished();
                $runner->runner_id = $request->runner_id;
                $runner->completed_steps = $completedSteps;
                $runner->save();
            }
```

It will work for (both array or single element )input of completed_steps and output will be an array always.

Suppose your runner_id is 1

input for completed_steps is 6

output for completed_steps is [6]

again your input for completed_steps is [1, 2, 3]

the output will be for completed_steps is [6, 1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it will help:

```
$runner = RunsAccomplished::where('runner_id', '=', runner_id())->first();

    if ($runner) {
        $runnerArray = $runner->toArray();

        $completed_steps = isset($runnerArray['completed_steps']) || $runnerArray['completed_steps'] != NULL ? $runnerArray['completed_steps'] : [];
        array_push($completed_steps, $request->input('completed_steps'));

        $runner->completed_steps = $completed_steps;
        $runner->weight = $request->input('weight');
        $runner->save();
    } else {
        $runner = new \App\Models\RunsAccomplished;
        $runner->shop_name = shop_id();
        $runner->weight = $request->input('weight');
        $runner->completed_steps = $request->input('completed_steps');
        $runner->save();
    }
```